# I need to understand the behaviour of these C pointers

Tags: c, pointers, undefined-behavior

Playing around pointers I produced a behavior that I can't explain. When I print a string in an accessory function I get a segfault in my main when printing an uninitialized char* (I see this is reasonable), the tricky part is if I do everything else the same way and don´t use the printf line in the accessory function, the program works perfectly, to the point that it surprisingly returns the address of the stack string implicitly.

Here is the program as I wrote and ran it (on Fedora 35 in an installation as vanilla as it gets). Even if you can't totally explain the issue any help in understanding this will be most welcome.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

/* This function generates a stack string and fills it */
char* generate_stack_string()
{
    char stack_string[70];
    strcpy(stack_string,"test");
    
    /*the next line is the one that when added crashes the program*/
    
    //printf("adress ( %p ) and text ( %s ) of stack string inside the function\n\n",stack_string, stack_string);
    
    
    //function compiles and runs normally despite no return value, but seems to return something anyhow
}
int main()
{   char *pointer_in_main;  
    //this pointer is never malloced, this is intentional, to provoke the behaviour
    
    printf("pointer_in_main adress before function call  %p\n\n",pointer_in_main);
    pointer_in_main = generate_stack_string();
    printf("pointer_in_main adress after function call  %p\n\n",pointer_in_main);
    
    //This is where program crashses when the heap string is printed
    printf("pointer_in_main content after function call %s\n\n",pointer_in_main);
    

}
```

Comment: `generate_heap_string` doesn't return a value, where ever `pointer_in_main` points is nonsense, and you try to read that location with your last `printf`, invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). UB before that in fact, `pointer_in_main` is never initialized to anything.

Comment: undefined behavior is undefined. You can change details of the code to get different behavior but it is still undefined.

Comment: Even though it is named heap_string, the char array is most definitely not on the heap, instead being on the stack.

Comment: **Undefined behavior** means anything can happen including but not limited to the program giving your expected output. But never rely on the output of a program that has UB.

Comment: " the program works perfectl" no it doesnt. Just because you do not get a compiler error and the output seems to be reasonable does not imply that the code is correct

Comment: Undefined behavior is a whole-program phenomenon.  Although it arises from execution of specific statements or evaluation of specific expressions with incorrect or invalid data, the effect is not limited to those particular statements or expressions.  It can even time travel, or at least appear to do, affecting execution of the program at points earlier in the program flow than the faulty statement or expression.

Comment: When you _know_ your program contains errors, and you just don't understand how they produces a particular result, you should at least try fixing them first. Either you prove they're not necessary to reproduce your problem, in which case you ruled something out and can post a question without distracting irrelevancies, or you prove they _are_ necessary and now your question can be much more specific.

Comment: I once wrote a program that segfaulted due to what I suspected was an invalid pointer. I added a `printf("%p\n", foo);` statement to verify this. It printed a value for the pointer that was, as expected, nowhere near the location it should have been...and then worked perfectly. Removing the statement caused the segfault to return.  That is, the program worked perfectly if and only if it first printed proof that it shouldn't work at all. Undefined behavior is *weird*.  The only option is to not have any in the first place.

Comment: @Useless, the question had no intention of asking for help debuging, it was just about having some fun with the compiler and trying to understand what was going on behind the scene. Think of it as reverse engineering the compiler. I agree that at beginner level this should not be my main focus, but still I got very curious about it. But the answer dbush gave me totally cleared my doubt.

Answer (score 1):

With the understanding that this is all undefined behavior, let's take a look at your function:

```
char* generate_stack_string()
{
    char stack_string[70];
    strcpy(stack_string,"test");
    
    /*the next line is the one that when added crashes the program*/
    
    //printf("adress ( %p ) and text ( %s ) of stack string inside the function\n\n",stack_string, stack_string);
    
    
    //function compiles and runs normally despite no return value, but seems to return something anyhow
}
```

This function is not returning a value, despite the fact that it is declared to do so.  The returning of a value from a function is typically performed by placing a value in a register.  Since there's no `return` statement, whatever value happened to be in the register in question will be the value returned.  And since the last statement in the function is also a function call, the value in the register is what was returned from *that* function.  In the case of `strcpy`, that happens to be the value of the first parameter, i.e. `stack_string` converted to a pointer.  So by luck you're returning the pointer you intended to return.

Running this code I get the following output:

```
pointer_in_main adress before function call  (nil)

pointer_in_main adress after function call  0x7ffe3c7cd3e0

pointer_in_main content after function call test
```

You were also "lucky" that the memory contents previously used by `stack_string` weren't overwritten when the last call to `printf` in `main` happens.

Now if we uncomment the `printf` call in `generate_stack_string`, I get the following output:

```
pointer_in_main adress before function call  (nil)

adress ( 0x7ffec0587ee0 ) and text ( test ) of stack string inside the function

pointer_in_main adress after function call  0x51

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Here we can see that a value was returned that is outside the valid address space of the process, so attempting to dereference it causes a segfault.  But what is this value?

Looking at the updated function, the last line executed is a call to `printf`.  This function returns the number of characters printed, and 0x51 (decimal 81) happens to be the number of characters printed.  So this value was left in the register used to return values from a function, so this is what was returned.

But again, this is all undefined behavior.   With the modified code, I get the same segfault regardless of optimization level.  If I run the original code with `-O1` or higher, I get this output:

```
pointer_in_main adress before function call  (nil)

pointer_in_main adress after function call  (nil)

pointer_in_main content after function call (null)
```

So when your program has undefined behavior, all bets are off.

Comment: Perfect! @dbush, your explanation is perfect, exactly what I needed to understand this conundrum!!! Thanks a ton. BTW, you wouldn't happen to know what on earth gives generate_stack_string() a free pass on the return thing? I get a " control reaches the end of a non-void function" wherever I forget to return (of course not on main) but here it just went silent, no warning, no nothing.

Comment: @FernandoLoula If you compile with `-Wall` you should get a warning for a missing `return`.

Comment: Indeed I did, @dbush. I actually got two warnings, one for missing return and one for uninitialized pointer. I leked this -Wall, will start to use it from now on.

Comment: @FernandoLoula You should also use `-Wextra` as well.

Answer (score 0):

For starters this statement

```
printf("pointer_in_main adress before function call  %p\n\n",pointer_in_main);
```

has undefined behavior because the pointer was not initialized and has an indeterminate value.

```
char *pointer_in_main;
```

This function returns nothing

```
char* generate_heap_string()
{
    char heap_string[70];
    strcpy(heap_string,"test");
    
    /*the next line is the one that when added crashes the program*/
    
    //printf("adress ( %p ) and text ( %s ) of heap string inside the function\n\n",heap_string,heap_string);
    
    
    //function compiles and runs normally despite no return value, but seems to return something anyhow
}
```

So again these calls of printf

```
pointer_in_main = generate_heap_string();
printf("pointer_in_main adress after function call  %p\n\n",pointer_in_main);

//This is where program crashses when the heap string is printed
printf("pointer_in_main content after function call %s\n\n",pointer_in_main);
```

invoke undefined behavior.

Even if you will change the function the following way

```
char* generate_heap_string()
{
    char heap_string[70];
    strcpy(heap_string,"test");
    
    /*the next line is the one that when added crashes the program*/
    
    //printf("adress ( %p ) and text ( %s ) of heap string inside the function\n\n",heap_string,heap_string);
    
    return heap_string;    
}
```

then nevertheless this call of printf

```
pointer_in_main = generate_heap_string();
//...
//This is where program crashses when the heap string is printed
printf("pointer_in_main content after function call %s\n\n",pointer_in_main);
```

will invoke undefined behavior one more time because the local array declared in the function will not alive after exiting the function and the pointer `pointer_in_main` has an invalid value.

That is in this call

```
//This is where program crashses when the heap string is printed
printf("pointer_in_main content after function call %s\n\n",pointer_in_main);
```

there is an attempt to dereference the invalid pointer.

The difference between the calls of printf is that in one case you are trying to print an invalid value of the pointer but in the other case

```
//This is where program crashses when the heap string is printed
printf("pointer_in_main content after function call %s\n\n",pointer_in_main);
```

you are using the invalid value to access memory.

Comment: Thanks for your input, sure is helpfull. But that is not exactly my question. I know the function not returning and using uninitialized pointers is wrong and will cause crashes, that is why I pointed those facts out in comments. My issue is trying to understand what is going on when I introduce that printf line. Whatever it is it is the diference between crashing and not crashing the program.

Comment: @FernandoLoula It is clear written in my answer that the local array is not alive. and the call of printf tries to dereference the invalid pointer.

Comment: I know it is a valid derefence. All I am trying to understand is why the presence or absence of a printf statement in another call stack makes this invalid call either work or crash.

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems in your program most of which leads to **undefined behavior**. For example, the pointer `pointer_in_main` is **uninitialized**
and you're using this pointer in the call to `printf` when you wrote:

```
printf("pointer_in_main adress before function call  %p\n\n",pointer_in_main);//this is undefined behavior because pointer_in_main is uninitialized
//whatever happens after this is not reliable
```

In the above call to `printf`, you're using the uninitialized pointer `pointer_in_main` which leads to **undefined behavior**.

> **Undefined behavior** means anything<sup>1</sup> can happen *including but not limited to* the program giving your expected output. But **never rely**(or make conclusions based) on the output of a program that has undefined behavior.

So the output that you're seeing(maybe seeing) is a result of undefined behavior. And as i said **don't rely on the output** of a program that has UB. The program may just **crash**.

So the first step to make the program correct would be to remove UB. **Then and only then** you can start reasoning about the output of the program.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>For a more technically accurate definition of undefined behavior see [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) where it is mentioned that: **there are no restrictions on the behavior of the program**.</sup>

Comment: I appreciate your answer very much, but that is not my question. I totally understand it is undefined behavior and that it is not correct to use an uninitialized pointer. I just want to understand what is happening, why printing in the other stack changes everything. Normally, with my little knowledge of pointers I can figure out what is going on with my crashes, but not in this case.

Comment: @FernandoLoula, at the level of the C language, undefined behavior *is* the reason for the crash.  It is rarely useful to look deeper, but if you do then that's the realm of the details of your C implementation.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, thanks for your guidance, honestly, real cool. Understanding the specifics of my compiler is very much beyond my current level, I just can't seem to let go of this problem. My impression is it has to do with a tiny piece of information about the workings of printf that if I knew would make it clear. Perhaps I could figure it out looking at the source code for printf, it should be available. Anyway, thanks again, your comment was positive and insightfull.